# Sort HashMap by Value in descending order

Tags: java

I have a HashMap with `Document` as Key and a `Double` Value as Value.

My aim is to sort the Hashmap by descending value. The `.reverse()` should be after `comparingbyValue()` but conflicts with sorted. How do I solve this?

```
HashMap<Document, Double> sortedMap = Map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Entry.comparingByValue())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: Does this even work? `sorted(Entry.comparingByValue())`. Probably should be `sorted(Entry::comparingByValue)` or an actual lambda.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap is fundamentally unsorted. TreeMap is fundamentally sorted on key. In other words, you can't do this. Just now how it works. You have two options:

### Figure out a way to sort on keys

And then just use a `TreeMap` with a custom comparator.

### Copy the whole thing

Make a tuple class, then copy the entire thing into an ArrayList by turning each k/v pair into a tuple, then sort that list on value as you want, then move the entire thing into a `LinkedHashMap` which preserves order. You **cannot** now modify the thing without going through this entire routine again.

### Rethink your architecture

If neither is acceptable you'll have to go back to the drawing board.

Comment: He is using `LinkedHashMap`. So it should be sorted by insertion order?